# How to find list of php files being run on my web server

Tags: ubuntu, web-server

Mine is Ubuntu VPS and all my sites are CMS based(Drupal, Wordpress etc) which run thru index.php.

My account has been hacked several times using some exploits by placing a php files and executing it. Those hackers aren't destructive but want to silently misuse my account by redirecting to different URLs in Google or sending spam all silently.

**So I just want to see list of php executables being run in Web server account(www-data) once in a day or month. Is there a way?**

I know one by reading the Apache access.log files and using the HTTP code 200 to find such files.

Is there any better way?

*(I hope Serverfault is the best place to ask this question, otherwise I'll delete and post it at any other  place)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to find *all* the PHP files, just the malicious ones. [Linux Malware Detect](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) is a good tool for this.

Of course, what you *really* should be doing is securing your server. Keep everything up to date, remove unnecessary modules/plugins, [harden WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) and Drupal, etc.

Comment: If a PHP file calls 10 functions from other php files then I don't want list of all php files but only the very first PHP file invoked from Apache.

Comment: That will not help you locate the malware, nor the entry point by which the server was compromised.